# Problems with knockout.js and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a page with dynamic tabs, using jQuery.UI tabs.
I have this code in my view:

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
<ul data-bind='foreach: sites'>
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { href: site().tabIdLink}"><span data-bind="text: site().Name"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- ko foreach: sites -->
<div data-bind="attr: { 'id': site().tabId }">
    <h3 data-bind="text: site().Name"></h3>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and this view model:

```
function ViewModel(api) {
    var self = this;

    self.sites = ko.observableArray([]);    
    self.addSite = function (data) {
        self.sites.push(new Site(data));
    };        

    $.getJSON(api + "allsites", "", function (allSites) {
        var mappedData = $.map(allSites, function (item)
        {
            return new Site(item);
        });
        self.sites(mappedData);
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
}

function Site(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.Id;
    self.tabId = "tab_" + data.Id;
    self.tabIdLink = "#" + self.tabId;
    self.site = ko.observable(data);
}
```

All works, except that I can't get the id property on the div tag to be set.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`site().tabId` won't work because `site` is an observable that holds the original data object that doesn't have the `tabId` property, consider doing this instead `$data.tabId` or just `tabId`

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

```
 <div data-bind="attr: { 'id': tabId }">
```